# "Invalid Cursor" error while running overloaded PLSQL stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am creating an overloaded PLSQL stored procedure which allows to display the names of schools, their corresponding category (elementary, etc), and neighbourhood they belong to.

The names of schools is taken from table `OTTAWASCHOOLS` from the field `NAME`. The category is taken from the table `OTTAWASCHOOLS` from the field `CATEGORY`.

In addition, the user has the choice to input a particular neighbourhood to find the above information of the schools in that neighbourhood. The name of the neighbourhood is taken from the `OTTAWANEIGHBOUR` table from the field `NAME`.

However, if the user does NOT input a specific neighbourhood, the output will display the names ALL the schools in the `OTTAWASCHOOLS` table with their respective neighbourhoods and categories

(I have created only one procedure at the moment).

My code is as follows

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE schools_package 
AS

PROCEDURE find_school
(neighbourhood_name     IN  OTTAWANEIGHBOUR.NAME%TYPE);
END schools_package;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY schools_package
AS
PROCEDURE find_school
(neighbourhood_name     IN  OTTAWANEIGHBOUR.NAME%TYPE)
IS

school_category             OTTAWASCHOOLS.CATEGORY%TYPE;
school_name                 OTTAWASCHOOLS.NAME%TYPE;
v_neighbourhood_name        OTTAWANEIGHBOUR.NAME%TYPE;

CURSOR c_schools IS
SELECT NAME, CATEGORY
FROM eluliGDM.OTTAWASCHOOLS;

r_schools c_schools%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
FOR r_schools IN c_schools
    LOOP
    SELECT c1.NAME, c2.NAME, c2.CATEGORY
    INTO v_neighbourhood_name, school_name, school_category
    FROM eluliGDM.OTTAWANEIGHBOUR c1, eluliGDM.OTTAWASCHOOLS c2
    WHERE  SDO_RELATE (c2.GEOMETRY, c1.GEOMETRY, 'MASK=INSIDE+COVEREDBY QUERYTYPE=JOIN') = 'TRUE'
    AND c2.NAME=r_schools.NAME;


    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NEIGHBOURHOOD  ' || 'CATEGORY  '|| 'SCHOOL NAME  ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('-------------  ' || '--------  '|| '-----------  ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_neighbourhood_name || school_category|| school_name);
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_schools;
END find_school;
END schools_package;

-----------TESTING STORED PROCEDURE---------------
Execute schools_package.find_school();
Execute schools_package.find_school('Mer Bleue');
```

But when I test the procedure, I get an error :`01001. 00000 -  "invalid cursor"` then proceeds to show me ALL neighborhoods and their corresponding schools. What is wrong with my cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `CLOSE c_schools;` statement.  The Cursor For Loop already takes care of that.  See [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155):

"The cursor FOR LOOP statement implicitly declares its loop index as a record variable of the row type that a specified cursor returns, and then opens a cursor. With each iteration, the cursor FOR LOOP statement fetches a row from the result set into the record. When there are no more rows to fetch, the cursor FOR LOOP statement closes the cursor."

Comment: I removed the `CLOSE c_schools;` I don't get an error anymore but the results are ALL the neighbourhoods and their corresponding schools (even though I specified a neighbourhood when I tested the procedure)

Comment: Well, that is a different problem now, isn't it?  I answered your question.  If you have a new problem, open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your typing, OTTAWASCHOOLS contains both columns NAME and CATEGORY, so the cursor itself appears to be validly defined.

OTOH, does schema eluliGDM own both the tables and the package?  If that is not the package owner, perhaps there are privilege issues?  If the schema is the same, why specify the schema in the code?  If not the same, consider the use of synonyms and removing the hard-coded schema from the code.

I'm not sure why you have an input parameter; you're not using it. So, I'm not surprised you're getting all the schools; the cursor has no predicate so it's the full table, and the SELECT inside the LOOP joins wherever the NAME column is the same in both tables.  Without anything to limit based on input parameter, you have no filters at all beyond the join.

HTH

Comment: eluliGDM owns both the tables and the package. I specified the schema due to the preference of my professor. I deleted it in the code to see what would happen, and I get the same error (Please see my comment under user OldProgrammer). I used an input parameter because I input the name of the neighbourhood